# Пуш данных в масив через forEach js

Tags: javascript, dom

```
    vitrats.forEach(function(item,i){
    let numbers = [];
    numbers.push(vitrats[i]);
    console.log(numbers[i]);
});
```

вот скрин сайта
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно подсчитать сумму всех вторых текстов.

Comment: Опять какой то ребус. Дополните вопрос, напишите нормально, что у вас не получилось, чего вы ожидали. И приведите код, из которого хотя бы видно, что вы перебираете в массиве. Пока ничего не понятно.

Comment: Мне нужно на сайте вычислить сумму всех растрат.Вот эти позиции которие на картинке, мне нужно вычислить сумму всех вторых текстов, позиций неограниченое количество, у чсех одинаковий класс.

Comment: let numbers = []; уберите из из  forEach

Comment: и консоль лог делайте за пределами forEach

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1111840/308951 сложение во втором примере

Comment: Спасибо большое за последний комент, никак не мог сделать

Answer (score -1):

```js
let numbers = [];
vitrats.forEach((e, i)=>{
    numbers.push(e);
    console.log(e);
});
console.log(numbers);
```

- e = element
- i = index

Comment: пс, лучше бы дал `сумму всех растрат` откуда берешь, ибо хз что там внутри `vitrats` и можно без второго(этого) цикла сделать всё, я думаю